# PhpMyAdmin Import Error-MySQL server has gone away/Unrecognized Keyword

Tags: mysql, php, import, phpmyadmin

So I've exported a MySQL database from PHPMyAdmin (which I access from within IIS Express on a Windows 8 machine) and I'm trying to import this database onto another machine, however on that machine I receive the following errors:

[image: Error]
[image: Warning1]
[image: Warning2]

Please help. I need to be able to restore this database and I have no idea how to fix this.

I tried going into the sql file and changing the foreign key line in the sql file (it was set to 0), but that didn't make a difference. Where is it set to ON? I can't figure that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the MySQL settings worked. This is what I changed, exactly:

**In php.ini**

Find:

```
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 8M
```

Change to:

```
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000M
```

**In my.ini (MySQL File)**

Under `mysqld` add: `max_allowed_packet = 500M`